# Nosetests is not running for some reason

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, nose

I'm going through the course of IBM for DevOps and Software Engineering and in one of the labs, I'm supposed to run some tests with the `nosetests` tool. This lab was designed to be done in a virtual environment, but I'd rather run it locally on my PC.

I cloned the git repo and installed `nosetests` with `pip3 install nose`. Then after I go to the root folder where the tests are located but with no success:

I tried to run it with the following methods:

1. `nosetests`
2. `python3 nosetests`
3. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/nosetests`

but none of them work.

they give the following error messages:

1. `zsh: command not found: nosetests`
2. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/georgiangelov/devops-school/duwjx-tdd_bdd_PracticeCode/labs/01_running_tests_with_nose/nosetests': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
3. 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/nosetests", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_exit())
             ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
    unittest.TestProgram.__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 179, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 193, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 481, in loadTestsFromNames
    return unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self, names, module)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 454, in loadTestsFromName
    return LazySuite(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 53, in __init__
    super(LazySuite, self).__init__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 22, in __init__
    self._tests = []
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 106, in _set_tests
    if isinstance(tests, collections.Callable) and not is_suite:
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that nosetests is not supported for python 3.11. It's recommended to migrate to PyTest.

[Nose is unmaintained and no longer works with Python 3.10 #1148](https://github.com/SyneRBI/SIRF/issues/1148)

Answer (score 1):

If people still need to use `nose`, it's been patched for newer versions of Python in `pynose`:
https://pypi.org/project/pynose/

`pip install pynose`, then you can run tests with `pynose` or `nosetests`.

Changes in `pynose` from legacy `nose` include:

- Fixes "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'."
- Fixes "AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'."
- Fixes "ImportError: cannot import name '_TextTestResult' from 'unittest'."
- Fixes "RuntimeWarning: TestResult has no addDuration method."
- Fixes all `flake8` issues from the original `nose`.
- Replaces the `imp` module with the newer `importlib` module.
- The default logging level now hides "debug" logs for less noise.
- The `-s` option is always active to see the output of `print()`.
- Adds `--co` as a shortcut to using `--collect-only`.

Answer (score 0):

use `pip install pynose`
I  got this error after run this command ,

> nosetest

worked correctly